# Ms-Access GROUP BY, TOP query

Tags: sql, group-by, ms-access-2007, limit

I am using the following query on a .mdb file with the following results.

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableA.type, tableA.date, SUM(tableA.val) AS total, tableB.SumB
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableB.id = tableA.id
GROUP BY tableA.id, tableA.type, tableA.date, tableB.SumB ;
```

results:

[image]

I need only the first record from the group of records with the same `type` and `date`.

I would use `DISTINCT` but the problem is that I have a different field (in this example `id`).

Any suggestions?

Thanks

P.S. Case 2:

Ids are the same for the red records but we have an additional column 'name' with different string values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use min of id and remove it from Group by clause

```
SELECT min(tableA.id) as id, tableA.type, tableA.date, 
SUM(tableA.val) AS total, tableB.SumB 
FROM tableA LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableB.id = tableA.id 
GROUP BY tableA.type, tableA.date, tableB.SumB ;
```

Comment: Thanks.

How about another case:  id is the same but I have another column(name) with different values?

Comment: In that case do you want to return only one name?

Comment: Then add min(name) as name in the select statement

Comment: I added min(name) but I still receive both records, and instead of column name I have (Expr1003)

Comment: should be min(name) as name and dont include that column in the group by clause